# On a starter motor what is TH?

Tags: mazda, starter

I have a 97 Mazda 323 Protege, with a B6D engine. While looking at new starter motors, there are a few different models that seem to be applicable to my car, one says 8TH another says 10TH, what is the difference?

Comment: What is the make/model/engine of the vehicle you're talking about?

Comment: I'm not sure how relative it is to the question, but it's a 97 Mazda 323 Protege, with a B6D engine

Comment: Thanks! It's relative because we need a frame of reference if we are to help you. Every manufacturer can label their starters differently and identify them in a different way.

Comment: Maybe 8 teeth and 10 teeth, maybe for different transmissions the 323 came with?

Comment: @Ben - That's what I was thinking as well ... trying to look things up on Aussie parts houses online.

Comment: In fact, I'm almost positive the 8TH and 10TH refers to the number of teeth on the starter gear drive, but I'm unsure how to differentiate which one your car will need ... other than, of course, taking the starter off and counting the teeth.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 in the US the protege had either a NipponDenso or Mitsubishi starter

Answer (score 2):

The difference is two teeth. On the Mazda 323, it's normally an 8tooth application (maybe the 10 teeth - which I don't see on parts sites - is for a standard transmission?).

Buy from a parts store that will allow you to return the wrong part, and get the 8 tooth one first. Or, remove the old starter and take it along with you.